# Angular 10 SSR in Dotnet Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, server-side-rendering

I'm currently trying to enable Angular 10 SSR with dotnet core 3.1.
I'm also using the Angular 10 template that is giving while creating an ASP.Net app.

I used this [guide](https://medium.com/@pieterjandeclippel/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-update-705c0ec01931) to try to enable it but I always get Dotnet Compilation errors saying that there are Duplicated Files.
Is there any other guide that I can follow?

Thanks for all information!